# Want to improve ANN presentation adding the activation functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

Well, there is actually two problems that I want to resolve, but I don't know if I should do two posts. Anyway...

I have this representation of my ANN and want to include the action functions, but I also don't know how to make it looks *better*

```
            \documentclass{article}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \begin{document}
            \pagestyle{empty}
            \def\layersep{1.5cm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
               shorten >=1pt,->,
               draw=black!50,
                node distance=\layersep,
                every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
                neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
                input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
                output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
                hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
                annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
            ]
                % Draw the input layer nodes
                \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
                % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};
                % set number of hidden layers
                \newcommand\Nhidden{2}
                % Draw the hidden layer nodes
                \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
                   \foreach \y in {1,...,12} {
                      \path[yshift=4cm]
                          node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y cm) {};
                       }
                \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
                }
                % Draw the output layer node
                \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-6] (O) {};

                % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
                % hidden layer.
                \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
                    \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                        \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
                % connect all hidden stuff
                \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
                   \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                       \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                           \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
                % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
                \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                    \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);
                % Annotate the layers
                \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
                \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            % End of code
            \end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can write text in the {} at the end of the \node lines. You'll have to spend some time tweaking the loops and distances though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write text in the curly brackets after the nodes (as below), however this ruins the spacing of the original drawing, and it looks really clouded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            \begin{document}
            \pagestyle{empty}
            \def\layersep{3cm}
            \def\nodeinlayersep{1.5cm}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
               shorten >=1pt,->,
               draw=black!50,
                node distance=\layersep,
                every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
                neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
                input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
                output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
                hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
                annot/.style={text width=4em, text centered}
            ]
                % Draw the input layer nodes
                \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
                % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
                    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};
                % set number of hidden layers
                \newcommand\Nhidden{2}
                % Draw the hidden layer nodes
                \foreach \N in {1,...,\Nhidden} {
                   \foreach \y in {1,...,12} {
                      \path[yshift=6cm]
                      node[hidden neuron] (H\N-\y) at (\N*\layersep,-\y*\nodeinlayersep ) {$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$};
                       }
                \node[annot,above of=H\N-1, node distance=1cm] (hl\N) {Hidden layer \N};
                }
                % Draw the output layer node
                \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H\Nhidden-6] (O) {};
%
                % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
                % hidden layer.
                \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
                    \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                        \path (I-\source) edge (H1-\dest);
                % connect all hidden stuff
                \foreach [remember=\N as \lastN (initially 1)] \N in {2,...,\Nhidden}
                   \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                       \foreach \dest in {1,...,12}
                           \path (H\lastN-\source) edge (H\N-\dest);
                % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
                \foreach \source in {1,...,12}
                    \path (H\Nhidden-\source) edge (O);
                % Annotate the layers
                \node[annot,left of=hl1] {Input layer};
                \node[annot,right of=hl\Nhidden] {Output layer};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            % End of code
            \end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to draw the graph of the function instead of the function? Is it too hard? @ThorbjørnEK

Comment: Yes, this can quite easily be done by exchanging `$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$` With `\tikz\draw[scale=0.05,samples=100,domain=-6:6,smooth,variable=\x,red,-] plot ({\x},{4/(1+exp(-\x))});` @CaioCustódio

Comment: @ThorbjørnEK worked with an error: '   Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/variabl‌​e', to which you passed '\x ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. }'

Comment: I don't get any error, so that's wierd.

Comment: I did it again and worked, maybe a case of bad copy & past. Thank you! So it works with every other kind of function? @ThorbjørnEK

Comment: One last question, I have been trying but I cannot add a "+" axis-like

Comment: A + axis? I don't get it

Comment: An axis with centered on point (0,0) @ThorbjørnEK

Comment: I think you'd have to draw it in paint or something for me to understand @CaioCustódio

Comment: Something like it https://i.imgur.com/AhHQrcL.png @ThorbjørnEK